# How can one block a port without administrator privileges?

Tags: java, tcp

I have found that binding to a port with a Java program prevents other applications from using the port in question. However, if an application is already using the port, a Java program cannot be used to do this. If administrator privileges are not available, how can one block traffic on such a port?

Comment: The answer is going to be highly specific to the system the JVM is running on. I think this is more of a StackOverflow question than a security question.

Comment: @schroeder how? I can see this being a security question. Although this question is littered with the word *"Java"* it's not really about that.

Comment: @iismathwizard it's about a programatic interface with an (unspecified) Operating system

Comment: @schroeder they're not specifically asking about how to do something with the JVM, though.. Yes, the operating system is unspecified and that's obviously not helping; however, the question is asking how to block traffic on a socket.

Comment: It *really* looks like the question is Java-specific ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try things like using the `netstat -o` command, or whatever alternative might be available on your platform, to identify the process which is using the port you want to block (assuming you don't know the offending process already). If you have enough access (usually meaning "if it's a program running in your user account"), you can then kill that process (or possibly forcibly close the socket using debug APIs, but this is tricky and platform-dependent) and open the socket yourself, without allowing shared access, thus blocking other processes from using it.

If you just want to block all traffic to (or from) a port, the best way to do that is probably at your router (assuming your computer isn't directly connected to the Internet). You may need a router password (not the same thing as the WiFi password) but you should then be able to block all traffic on a certain port, or direct it to another computer.

It should be noted that you can't stop an admin from un-blocking the port, if they try. They could kill your process that is holding the port open. They could maybe even prevent you from opening the port at all, using something like AppArmor or the Windows advanced firewall. They can also just create a process that runs at system startup (before you even log in) and reserves that port via a process that non-admins cannot kill.

Answer (score 0):

Ports 1024 and below are considered 'privileged' ports, and hence only users with root level access can run services on these ports.  Ports 1025 and higher are not considered to be privileged ports, so any user can run services on these.  See http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html for more info.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.